# C++ extract .reg file to registry

Tags: c++, registry

Can anyone tell me please how to extract the data from a .reg file into the registry?

I've tried:

```
 system("regedit /s product.reg");
```

It doesn't work, I have also looked at various other questions on here but have had no joy and I have also trouble understanding them.

Can anyone shed any light or send me a link that has a good example please?

Thanks

Comment: When you attempt to call `system` what happens? Any errors? Any windows popping up? Anything else besides "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Sorry should have said, No errors, No windows, nothing. It just does not update the registry.

Comment: REG.EXE made no difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following things applies to Windows Vista / Windows 7 and later version.

You won't be able to successfully execute regedit.exe unless your application is not running with Administrator privilege.

If you're using Visual Studio 2005/2008/2010, go to the property window of your project, expand the 'Linker' options, and select 'Manifest File'. Change UAC Execution Level to 'requireAministrator'. Save your project and rebuild your project.

Comment: Done this, made no difference, running with no errors just not adding the data to the registry

Comment: Took me a while to realise my issue, as i was using MsiGetProperty to get the path I did not realise there was spaces in my path.

Spaces = Cant read .reg file

@Rango Your answer was also very helpful, thank you. I'm marking your answer as correct as I think it may help people with the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://commandwindows.com/reg.htm), the correct command is:

```
reg IMPORT <FileName>
```

Comment: Tried this, did not work either. Im not sure what is wrong..:(

Comment: Well, someone else has answered that you should have Administrator privileges to change the registry. Have you tried combining the command I provided with Administrator privileges? If not, I do not know what it might be.

Comment: your command works fine on the command line. Is the answer above the only way to have an MSI run as an administrator?

Comment: I don't know. I am not very fluent with that Windows Administrator privileges thing. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
system("product.reg")
```

should also work. This is akin to double-clicking the file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're on Windows anyway: `ShellExecuteA("product.reg")`. Unlike `system`, this won't start a console window.